# Sending text data to remote socket using Arduino Ethernet library

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am trying to accomplish something. The thing is, I have an arduino with some sensors, and I want to record their readings from my office and send the data to my computer at home. I used Arduino Ethernet shield to connect the arduino to the internet, and to send data, I used EthernetClient. To receive the data, I used a TCP socket running at address "1111" on my home computer. But when I want to send the data to my home computer, it says that the connection failed.

I have forwarded two ports on my home machine, port 80 and port 1111. When I log onto the home PC using IP Address and port 80 on a browser, it shows me my HTTPD server hosted there. But, when I connect to the same IP Address and port 80 using a Arduino, the connection fails.

Here is my code:

## 1. Arduino:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

IPAddress server(100, 65, 91, 226); // <<<<<<< My server Address
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 177);

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
while (!Serial);

if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
  Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
}


delay(1000);
Serial.println("connecting...");

if (client.connect(server, 1111)) {
  Serial.println("connected");
} else {
  Serial.println("connection failed");
}
}

void loop() {
    client.println("data to be sent");  
}
```

## 2. Python

```
import socket
import time

sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
if not sck:
    print "Could not create a socket for listening on this machine!"
else:
    print "Successfully created a socket"

sck.bind(("", 1111))
sck.listen(20)

print "listening to socket 111"


def listen():
    while True:
        clientSocket, clientAddr = sck.accept()
        if not clientSocket:
            print "No connection yet!"
            continue

        print "connected with", clientAddr
        while True:
            receiv = clientSocket.recv(4096)
            print receiv
            if not receiv:
                print "Client lost connection!"
                listen()

listen()
```

I am relatively new to arduino. However, when I try to send data to the python socket using another machine on a different network, it is successful. Arduino just cant seem to connect to the socket. What can I do? 
Thank you!